# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined while trying to run jquery code in console on wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The ollowing jquery code runs perfectly on all other sites except for wordpress based site.

> !function(t,e){function n(e,n,h){e||(e="div");var
>   i,o,a=t(n.container),c=a.offset()||{left:0,top:0},s=[c.left+a.width(),c.top+a.height()],f={x:0,y:1,w:0,h:1};for(i
>   in
>   f)f.hasOwnProperty(i)&&(o=r.exec(n[i]),o&&(n[i]=s[f[i]]*o[1]/100));var
>   u=a.find(e),l=[],d=!!n.furthest,p=!!n.checkHoriz,y=!!n.checkVert,v=d?0:1/0,x=parseFloat(n.x)||0,g=parseFloat(n.y)||0,k=parseFloat(x+n.w)||x,w=parseFloat(g+n.h)||g,F=n.tolerance||0,H=!!t.fn.each2,S=Math.min,m=Math.max;!n.includeSelf&&h&&(u=u.not(h)),0>F&&(F=0),u[H?"each2":"each"](function(e,r){var
>   h,i,o,a,c=H?r:t(this),s=c.offset(),f=s.left,u=s.top,M=c.outerWidth(),j=c.outerHeight(),z=f+M,O=u+j,P=m(f,x),V=S(z,k),W=m(u,g),X=S(O,w),Y=V>=P,b=X>=W;(p&&y||!p&&!y&&Y&&b||p&&b||y&&Y||p&&n.onlyX||y&&n.onlyY)&&(h=Y?0:P-V,i=b?0:W-X,o=n.onlyX?h:n.onlyY?i:Y||b?m(h,i):Math.sqrt(h*h+i*i),a=d?o>=v-F:v+F>=o,a&&(v=d?m(v,o):S(v,o),l.push({node:this,dist:o})))});var
>   M,j,z,O,P=l.length,V=[];if(P)for(d?(M=v-F,j=v):(M=v,j=v+F),z=0;P>z;z++)O=l[z],O.dist>=M&&O.dist<=j&&V.push(O.node);return
>   V}var
>   r=/^([\d.]+)%$/;t.each(["nearest","furthest","touching"],function(r,h){var
>   i={x:0,y:0,w:0,h:0,tolerance:1,container:document,furthest:"furthest"==h,includeSelf:!1,checkHoriz:"touching"!=h,checkVert:"touching"!=h};t[h]=function(r,h,o){if(!r||r.x===e||r.y===e)return
>   t([]);var a=t.extend({},i,r,o||{});return
>   t(n(h,a))},t.fn[h]=function(e,r){var h;if(e&&t.isPlainObject(e))return
>   h=t.extend({},i,e,r||{}),this.pushStack(n(this,h));var
>   o=this.offset(),a={x:o.left,y:o.top,w:this.outerWidth(),h:this.outerHeight()};return
>   h=t.extend({},i,a,r||{}),this.pushStack(n(e,h,this))}})}(jQuery);

above fails on wordpress sites with `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

The jQuery gets injected into the  header, but when I try to run any jquery code, it will not run.

I've been reading it and it seems like wordpress has something to do with it.

Comment: Are you trying to run this on the front-end or back-end of your WordPress site?

Comment: Try using `jQuery.fn.jquery;` in the console and seeing what jQuery version it outputs.

Comment: @DrCord: That won't do anything if `jQuery is not defined`.

Comment: duh, I am trying to help them find out if it is defined and something else is wrong.

Comment: Show us your `jquery` code. And where you have placed your custom `jquery` code? before `</head>` or `</body>`

Comment: It all depends on how and where said code is being included.

Comment: I copy pasted it in to my console. usually it works without complaints but on wordpress site, it seems to not work. jquery gets injected inside <script>. I have been able to verify this by runnign `$(document)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you load jquery before load your jquery code. When you say - "The jQuery gets injected into the header" - I hope it does not mean you are using some js to inject jquery on-fly
2. I caught this once - if you setup your server improperly, the js file header become [Content-Type:application/javascript] , however, it needs to be [Content-Type:text/javascript]; If you are using Nginx, you may need look into the settings for [default_type]